# C languange 4 digit possible variations with exception

Tags: c, equality

So i have a homework, but i can't wrap my head around why this code doesn't work.

Problem sounds something like this:

Make a code that checks all possible variations of 4 digit number, but there are no 3 same digits in a number. ( i hope that makes sense)

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main ()
{
        int i;
        char a,b,c,d;

        for (i=0; i<9999; i++)
        {
                a = i/1000;
                b = i/100%10;
                c = i/10%10;
                d = i%10;

                if (a==b==c)    {i++;}
                else if (b==c==d)       {i++;}
                else if (c==d==a)       {i++;}
                else if (d==a==b)       {i++;}
                else if (a==b==c==d)    {i++;}

                else
                {
                        printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n", a,b,c,d);
                }
        }
}
```

I want it to print out something like this:

```
0,0,1,1
0,0,1,2
0,0,1,3
...
0,1,0,9
0,1,1,0
0,1,1,2
...
9,9,8,8
```

Instead it prints:

```
0,1,2,2
0,1,3,3
0,1,4,4
0,1,5,5
0,1,6,6
...
0,8,6,6
0,8,7,7
0,8,8,8
0,8,9,9
0,9,2,2
...
9,9,9,8
```

Comment: The expression `a==b==c` is actually equal to `a==(b==c)` which means you're comparing `a` with the *boolean* result of `b == c`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `printf("0==4==3 is %s\n", 0==4==3?"true":"false");` or `printf("0==(4==3) is %s\n", 0==(4==3)?"true":"false");` ... [https://ideone.com/sRY0Gb](https://ideone.com/sRY0Gb)

Comment: @pmg Damn, got the associativity wrong. It's `(a == b) == c`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: also `b == c` yields a `int` result; `0`or `1` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem with these comparisons:

```
 if (a==b==c)
```

This doesn't find out if `a`, `b` and `c` are all the same. The result of `==` is `0` or `1`, and then that is compared to the third number. So per example if all three numbers are `9`, then `9==9==9` turns into `1==9`, which is `0`, so the `if` is not taken. What's more, you have false positives for things like `9==9==1`.

What you instead need here is

```
if ((a==b) && (a==c))
```

Now you check if `a` is equal to `b`, and when it is, you check it with `c`, and the `if` is taken if they're all the same.

Likewise of course for the other comparisons, so instead of `else if (a==b==c==d)` you want `else if ((a==b) && (a==c) && (a==d))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have noted, you can't chain comparison operators in C and get the expected results. Use logical operators to combine comparisons. It would probably be more clear to use `||` to avoid all of the `else` statements.

There is another significant problem with the posted code: `i` is incremented whenever a failing number is found. But then `i` is incremented again by the `for` loop. This causes the number after a failing number to be skipped, so some desired numbers will not be found. For example, `3222` should fail, and the subsequent number `3223` should pass, but this number is skipped by the posted code (after the comparison corrections), with the next number to be checked `3224`. Instead, just use `continue`:

```
if ((a == b && a == c) ||
    (b == c && b == d) ||
    (c == d && c == a) ||
    (d == a && d == b) ||
    (a == b && a == c && a == d)) {
    continue;
} else {
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n", a,b,c,d);
}
```

Comment: It would be better just to negate the test and put the `printf` in the `if` block and thus eliminate the `continue`

Comment: @JeremyP -- I'm sure that there are better ways to express this, but I wanted to stay close to OP's logic and to focus on the correction to comparison operator usage and the mistaken extra increment to `i`. That said, the modified code I wrote seems pretty clear, and I'm not sure that using negation would add to that clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use multiple equalities like this. You have to do them separately with and conditions (e.g. `a==b && b==c`).

Comment: "You can't use multiple equalities." - yes you can, it's just that it has a different meaning to writing it another way.